# How to apply vertical-align inside inline-table

Tags: html, css

As in the question :) I would like to verticaly center my text inside links. I tried to handle this problem without srcipt but my ideas doesn't work. Also, I don't want to lose my 100% height of "a" elements. Thank you in advance for any approach of my problem. I am using twitter bootstrap 3

```
        .navbar-wrapper {

            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 20;
        }

        .navbar .navbar-nav {

            display: block;
            float: none;
        }

        .navbar .navbar-nav > li {

            display: table-cell;
            float: none;    
        }

        .navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {

            display: inline-table;
            height: 100%;
        }  


        /*.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a > span {

            vertical-align: middle;

        } */
```

and html:

```
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
                            <li><a href="#"><span>level 1 line 1<br />line 2</span></a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#about"><span>level 1</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact"><span>level 1 line 1<br />line 2</span></a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-first-level" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li> 
                        </ul> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `display:block` on the `a` element, instead of `display: inline-table;`

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
}
```

**[Updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/N93L3/1/)**

**Note:** If, for some reason you need to set `display: inline-table;` on the `a` element, then

just make sure that the direct children of the table have the following rules:

1) `display: table-cell;`
2) `vertical-align: middle;`

In this case:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/N93L3/2/)**

Comment: I am sorry @Danield but I didn't write I am using twitter bootstrap 3.  BTW Both of solutions don't work. First doesn't stretch background-color of active element to 100% height of parrent. Second destroy my navigation a little :)